Looking for a 90's horror movie that had a girl with gills
This is probably the first horror movie I ever watched. It would have been before 1999 I was probably about 4 and I sneaked and watched it until my parents caught me and sent me to bed. My memory may be foggy because it was quite long ago but this is what I remember. It also could possibly be before the 90's but I'm pretty sure it was from the 90's.
One scene featured an attractive Caucasian brunette girl and she seemed to have gills like a shark forming on her stomach. She was breathing heavily and seemed to be freaking out. She had a group of friends male and female maybe 3+ people around her age all nursing her and carrying her down the stairs and putting her down gently and trying to nurse her back to health. They seemed to be in a stereotypical 90's suburban house. 
From that scene it would cut to what I assume was the backyard of the house. And there was a chain that had come to life by it's self and it was going wild and trying to hit a guy who was outside there. And I think it smashed objects in it's reach. 
Thank you in advanced. I hope I'm remembering it clearly. She may have even had slashes on her stomach. But I don't remember any blood. They really just looked like gills. I'm obsessed with horror and I remember this being the first piece of media I was ever interested in. So it would be really cool to watch it properly. 

The Kindred, (1987).

A geneticist takes his assistants to his old family home to locate the
  deadly product of his late mother's revolutionary research into rapid
  human evolution - his monstrous tentacled baby brother, before a mad
  scientist gets to him first.

The "chain that came to life by itself" was the tentacle of an offscreen sea creature.  The brunette girl with the gills was Amanda Pays, of Max Headroom fame.  You can see the scene you describe in the trailer.
